# My left menu and submenu covers my entire page on low bandwidth

Tags: html, css

I have a left menu, and when I hover to a menu item a submenu open and when clicking on the submenu, the background covers my entire page if the internet is slow, and then goes back as it was.

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 478px) {
   nav.main-menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 72px;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1010;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 60px;
      height: 100%;
      background: #333333;
      -moz-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
      -o-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
      -moz-transition: width 0.05s linear;
      -o-transition: width 0.05s linear;
      -webkit-transition: width 0.05s linear;
      transition: width 0.05s linear;
      transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
   }

   nav.main-menu > ul {
      margin: 7px 0;
   }

   nav.main-menu li {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 250px;
   }
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: can you add jsfiddle?

Comment: internet speed wouldn't effect this, what else do you have going on?

Comment: The background of the main menu cover the page and then goes back as it was. Ok it the browser fault its on IE 8 and EI9

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle with some HTML code.

Comment: Unfortunately its a huge code, I will take time to add what is necessary and what is not. Do you know what can prevent the background to get cover the screen when you load a webpage

Answer (score 0):

Deleted this part and it worked fine:

```
 -moz-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transition: width 0.05s linear;
  -o-transition: width 0.05s linear;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.05s linear;
  transition: width 0.05s linear;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
```